# Data Lake ,Layers and ETL processing on GCP

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-platform

[image]

I am coming from on-prem/hadoop data-platform background and now want to understand the good practices of doing this on GCP cloud technologies.

As shown in the diagram, I have used HDFS/Hive to store the data for all 3 layers: "Landing","Cleansed" and "Processed". For the ETL processes,I have used Spark.This also supports different ingestion patterns : insert new records , insert as well as update previous data.

For the "serving layer" we have used Presto.
Also with new technologies like DeltaLake, is possible to keep almost the same architecture to supported both streaming and batch processing in unified manner.

On GCP there are following options I can think of:

Option 1:

- "Landing layer" is Google Storage.
- DataFlow "ETL process" transforms and load data into the "Cleansed Layer"."Cleansed Layer" is
  stored as BigQuery tables.
- "Cleaned Layer" to "Processed Layer" ETL is done inside BigQuery itself

Option 2:

- "Landing layer" is Google Storage.
- DataFlow/DataProc "ETL process" transforms and store data in the "Cleansed Layer"."Cleansed Layer" is stored in Cloud Store.
- "Cleaned Layer" to "Processed Layer" ETL is done using DataFlow/DataProc and the "Processed Layer" is in Cloud Store as well.
- "Service Layer" is BigQuery tables."Processed Layer" to Bigquery load is done with denormalization for BigQuery performance.

My questions :

1. As explained in Option 1: is it a good practice to perform ETL inside BigQuery itself? (using BQ DML statements). I am under the impression that heavy ETL should not be done in BQ as its not designed for heavy data mutations.
2. In Option2 : "Processed Layer" to BigQuery load can be done using b'q load' if the data ingestion pattern is insert only.What if we have to update previous data? In this case how to use bq-load as it only supports append and replace/overwrite modes only.Replacing a large table just to update a portion of its records is not performant.
3. What's the general good practice to do ETL and handle updates to BQ table?

Comment: funny "css/html" developer has mark this question as Closed.If you work in big data field, this is a valid architecture question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to design this solution, here is my suggestion:

[image]

**Data Lake:**
Load data from source system to BigQuery as-is, so the database operations will be only INSERT.

**Data Hub:**
Here, you can maintain OLTP structure, but implement Slowly Changing Dimension (Type-II). 
 (A) INSERT data for all new transactions 
(B) INSERT for exiting transactions also with UPDATE only the operational columns like END_DATE & ACTIVE_FLAG. So, you can maintain history of records.

[image]

[image]

**Data Analytics:**
Here, you can build Dimensional Modeling with SCD Type-II like Data Hub to minimize huge DML operations like UPDATE

Comment: thanks. have you implemented this reference architecture?　i was going through many reference architectures but couldnt find anyone doing ETL inside BQ

Comment: Yes, it is already in production. So far, it is running very nice :-)

Comment: whats the rough data volume?　and often you update the tables?

Comment: On an average around 10-15 million incremental records (10-20 columns) at a time. UPDATE happens only for 2 columns (operational) only !